# Insert based on Another Insert with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to run two insert statements in two different tables. 
The sqls are as under :

```
INSERT INTO Table1 ('t1_name', 't1_class') VALUES ('Joe','8');
```

Table1 has an autoincremental ti_id column

```
INSERT INTO Table2 ('t2_ti_id','t2_course') VALUES(< 'ti_id' from Table1 call >,
      'English'),(< 'ti_id' from Table1 call >, 'Math').
```

So end result should have been, such that the autoincremental id set for table1 query is used in the table2 query

```
Table1 

t1_id     ti_name    t1_class     
   1        Joe          8


Table2

 t2_id    t2_t1_id    t1_course
   1         1         English
   2         1          Math
```

t1_id and t2_t1_id have a foreign key setup

Please tell me how to make thecalls from the same sql, so that i dont have to make a seperate perl script for this

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is this? `(1, 'ti_id' from Table1 call, 'Math').`? Doens tmatch the amount of columns i cannot see how that would work?

Comment: Thanks Kay for pointing that out .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [last_insert_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (t1_name, t1_class) VALUES ('Joe','8');

SET @t1id = SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();

INSERT INTO Table2 (t2_ti_id, t2_course) 
VALUES (@t1id,'English')
```